# Proof of continuity of norm in function space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

How would you go about proving that the norm induced by the scalar product 
$$ \int_a^b f\cdot g \mathop{dx}$$
in the space $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$ is continuous?
Trying to calculate 
$$ \left|\int_a^b |f|^2 \mathop{dx} - \int_a^b |g|^2 \mathop{dx} \right|$$ 
it is clear that I can find an upper bound for this quantity provided that $f$ and $g$ are "close enough", but what notion of proximity should I use? 
The same norm? Wouldn't the reasoning be circular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm which induces the topology is always continuous (for the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$) since you can write that

$$x=x-y+y\text{ so }||x||\leq ||x-y||+||y||\text{ and then }||x||-||y||\leq ||x-y||,$$

and also

$$||y||-||x||\leq ||x-y||,$$

which leads to

$$\big|||x||-||y||\big|\leq||x-y||,$$

so the norm is $1$-lipschitz and so continuous.

Comment: If you call the norm $f$ just for fun, what I read here is $|f(x)-f(y)|\lt f(x-y) $ which doesn't feel like the definition of continuity

Comment: Yes: the norm here is both the function and the way to compute distances in your vector space.

Comment: Ok. On the first line did you mean for the usual topology on $\mathcal{C}([a,b])$?

Comment: No, here in this general example I deal with a normed space $(E,||\cdot||)$ and with $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ (that is, the topology induced by the absolute value - this is what I wanted to precise).

Comment: @Karl ??? No, the inequality $|f(x)-f(y)|\le f(x-y)$ is not the definition of continuity.  But here that's the same as $|f(x)-f(y)|\le d(x,y)$, which obviously implies $f$ is continuous (let $\delta=\epsilon$).